# To add the list-items on the table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular6

I have an `autocomplete` component,which consists of list of customers, below the `autocomplete` component `table` component is there as shown below image:

[image]

**The table is empty by default**. Now when i `choose/click` from `customer-list(i,e autocomplete)` component i should display the details of that customers in the table something like this:

[image]

Stackblitz **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u3hnly-8xn9tr?file=index.html)**

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I think i have explained the question properly..:)@TeunvanderWijst

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Demo with option selected from autocomplete is inserted into Table](https://angular-add-element-from-autocomplete.stackblitz.io)**

- Use `optionSelected` event on `mat-autocomplete` as  `(optionSelected)="selectedOption($event)"`
- Initialize an arry to store all the selected data, say  `selectedtableData: PeriodicElement[] = []`.

See this Code to handle the requirement:

```
const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [ 
{position: 1, email: 'customer1@gmail.com', name: 'Customer 1'}, 
{position: 2, email: 'customer2@gmail.com', name: 'Customer 2'},  
{position: 3, email: 'customer3@gmail.com', name: 'Customer 3'},  
{position: 4, email: 'customer4@gmail.com', name: 'Customer 4'} ];

selectedOption(event) {    
     const selectedValue = event.option.value;  
     let selectedvalueArr: PeriodicElement = ELEMENT_DATA.find(e=>e.name==selectedValue);
     selectedvalueArr && this.selectedtableData.push(selectedvalueArr)
     this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.selectedtableData);
 }
```

**Application Code :** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-add-element-from-autocomplete?file=app%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.ts

**Update 1 :** 
For making unique serial number :

**Code :** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-add-element-from-autocomplete-cexyka?file=app/autocomplete-filter-example.ts

Comment: This is the exact thing i was looking for, thank you.

Comment: Can i increment the No column, In ascending on adding random `customers`. means if i add `customer 4` first his `no` will be `1`, then if i add `customer 1` his `no` will be `2`.... so on. is it is possible?

Comment: Please see this, for that : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-add-element-from-autocomplete-cexyka?file=app/autocomplete-filter-example.ts

Comment: Thanks for your reply...:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use filtering on table with @angular/material like you use in your example. Here is the documentation for it: [Angular Material Table Filtering](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#filtering).

You can use the `optionSelected` output on the `mat-autocomplete`, to set table value when an option is selected. And clear table value when the input change.

I made a quick example on Stackblitz by modifying your demo: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u3hnly-rd2b6q?file=app%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.ts).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Now i am able to add from the `list ` i,e fine . But the we should add more than one .means table must increase on adding from the list.